# Optimizing `Canvas.drawCircle` with predefined `Path`

Tags: android, performance, animation, android-canvas

I'm currently learning animations in android and here's what I read in manual:

> A common mistake is to create a new Paint or a new Path every time a
>   rendering method is  invoked. This forces the garbage collector to run
>   more often and also bypasses caches and  optimizations in the hardware
>   pipeline.

and

> Complex shapes, paths, and circles for instance, are rendered using
>   texture masks. Every time you create or modify a path, the hardware
>   pipeline creates a new mask, which can be expensive.

In my application I plan to constantly draw dozens of circles and I want to optimize this process as well as possible. I have a method `Canvas.drawCircle(X, Y, RADIUS, Paint)` where I can supply a predefined `Paint` but not a predefined `Path`.

Question is: if I could provide a predefined `Path` as well as `Paint`, would that improve rendering performance? If yes, what method or technique should I use instead of `drawCircle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a Path here at all, so do not worry about predefined paths.
You do not need to optimize your code, unless you see it becomes slow, which should not be the case. 
One possible optimization is if you draw many times a circle of the same radius and same paint (but in different positions), render it once into a bitmap, and then draw that bitmap at each location. If you do this, do not prepare the bitmap in the onDraw method, prepare it only when it has to be changed.